# Java: Use getter vs caching value

Tags: java, performance

I have a getter that returns a String and I am comparing it to some other String.  I check the returned value for null so my `if`statement looks like this (and I really do exit early if it is true)

```
if (someObject.getFoo() != null && someObject.getFoo().equals(someOtherString)) {
  return;
}
```

Performancewise, would it be better to store the returned String rather than calling the getter twice like this?  Does it even matter?

```
String foo = someObject.getFoo();
if (foo != null && foo.equals(someOtherString)) {
  return;
}
```

---

To answer questions from the comments, this check is not performed very often and the getter is fairly simple.  I am mostly curious how allocating a new local variable compares to executing the getter an additional time.

Comment: I suppose this depends on how often you will be comparing Strings in this fashion.  How often will that be?

Comment: this is a micro-optimization at best.

Comment: I would do it just for readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends entirely on what the getter does. If it's a simple getter (retrieving a data member), then the JVM will be able to inline it on-the-fly if it determines that code is a hot spot for performance. This is actually why Oracle/Sun's JVM is called "HotSpot". :-) It will apply aggressive JIT optimization where it sees that it needs it (when it can). If the getter does something complex, though, naturally it could be slower to use it and have it repeat that work.

If the code isn't a hot spot, of course, you don't care whether there's a difference in performance.

Someone once told me that the inlined getter can sometimes be faster than the value cached to a local variable, but I've never proven that to myself and don't know the theory behind why it would be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second block.  The first block will most likely get optimized to the second anyway, and the second is more readable.  **But the main reason** is that, if someObject is ever accessed by other threads, and if the optimization somehow gets disabled, the first block will throw no end of NullPointerException exceptions.

Also:  even without multi-threading, if someObject is by any chance made *volatile*, the optimization will disappear.  (Bad for performance, and, of course, **really** bad with multiple threads.)  And lastly, the second block will make using a debugger easier (not that *that* would ever be necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the first null check since equals does that for you:

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

So the best solution is simply:

```
if(someOtherString.equals(someObject.getFoo())
```

Answer (score 0):

They both look same,even Performance wise.Use the 1st block if you are sure you won't be using the returned value further,if not,use 2nd block.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second code block because it assigns foo and then foo cannot change to null/notnull.

Null are often required and Java should solve this by using the 'Elvis' operator:

```
if (someObject.getFoo()?.equals(someOtherString)) {
  return;
}
```